# Does hot swapped compiled class remain in Tomcat after restart?

Tags: java, tomcat, hotswap

In case I compile a Java file in my IDE, (i.e. `IntelliJ`) and Hot Swap it to remote server (`Tomcat`, in that case.)

If I restart Tomcat - will it use the "new" compiled class ?

Comment: It seems like a simple case - have you tried it yourself?